# Swift - Get data from Alamofire POST request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm stuck in Swift project. I call "SendPost" from button IBAction and I need it returns the data from Alamofire.request, but I don't know how to reach this. I can't get to "utf8Text" variable from out of Alamofire.request. How can I get to the data?

Thank you. :)

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire


  func SendPost(parameters: Parameters) -> String {

  Alamofire.request("https://hovnocuc.com/main.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).response { response in
        print("Request: \(response.request)")
        print("Response: \(response.response)")
        print("Error: \(response.error)")

        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data: \(utf8Text)")

        }
    }

 return "I don't know. :(";
 }
```

Comment: You have a rogue end bracket at the if let line. Remove it then try again

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 3**

Use a completion to return de data obtained from Request:

First create a `typealias` which will be used as a closure :

`typealias SendPostCompletion = (_ data: String) -> Void`

Then:

```
@IBAction func yourAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        SendPost(parameters: ...) { (data) in
            print(data)
        }
}

func SendPost(parameters: Parameters, completion: @escaping SendPostCompletion) -> String {

        Alamofire.request("https://hovnocuc.com/main.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).response { response in
            print("Request: \(response.request)")
            print("Response: \(response.response)")
            print("Error: \(response.error)")

            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                var data = ("Data: \(utf8Text)")
                completion(data)
            }
        }

        completion("I don't know. :(")
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code

```
func SendPost(parameters: Parameters) -> [String,AnyObject] {

       let urlstring= "https://hovnocuc.com/main.php" 
       Alamofire.request(.POST, urlstring, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in

                       if let JSON = response.result.value {
                           print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                           return JSON 
                       }
                   }
               return "I don't know "
            }
```